# What keyboard shortcuts in Illustrator to make this?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustration, graphic-styles

My cat walked on my keyboard and then this happened. She change my logo like this. It look like outline logo. And I never know this technique before. I used macbook. What the keyboard shortcuts to make this. thanks you so much[image].

Comment: It's pretty unclear to me what you mean without seeing the original. I guess it happened to the selected paths... but not knowing what it looked like before, I can only guess what you mean.

Comment: Your **cat drew that antennae** just by walking on the keyboard?? That's a good cat. Keep it safe, it'll make you famous.

Comment: Looks like Offset Path, but I'm not aware of a shortcut for this. Also it would open a dialogue box. So your cat must have some advanced skills you're not aware of.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't it just white fills and black strokes? Maybe the cat pressed:

- `CMD` + `A` to select all.
- `D` to apply the "Default Fill and Stroke".

Comment: kitty has a little clean up to do on that chimney

Comment: hahahaha :D I like the answer.